# Trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell Precision 3530 mobile workstation (laptop)

Tags: boot, uefi, dell

As the subject says, I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell Precision 3530 laptop.

The installation seems to work, but afterwards the system is unbootable. The error looks like:

> No boot device Found. Press any key to reboot the machine.

I've tried playing around in the BIOS/UEFI, but got nowhere. I suspect there's a Secure Boot issue or something, but I don't really know.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install in UEFI boot mode? How you boot install media, UEFI or old BIOS is then how it installs.

Dual boot or just Ubuntu?

Dell typically needs UEFI update, SSD firmware update, change to AHCI and fast boot in UEFI off. If still Windows fast start up off in Windows. If really new system, may need 20.04 to have newest drivers for Dell.

If nVidia you may need nomodeset boot parameter if you did not install driver.

Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Shows installer with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Also shows Windows 10 screens or similar to Windows 8

[How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi)

Comment: I needed to install with UEFI enabled.  Thanks!

Comment: BTW, it's "just ubuntu" - I'm happy to say Microsoft Windows has ever touched this computer.